# Conditional Import external package with ESLint

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint

I'm trying to import a package and use it in my Vue application as follows

```
import ExternalSamplePackage from 'external-sample-package'

export default {
 directives: {
  ExternalSamplePackage
 }
}
```

I'm in SSR mode, so I want to conditionally import the package like this:

```
if(process.client) {
 import ExternalSamplePackage from 'external-sample-package'
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error on my es-lint:

```
> error  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

How can I import with the right es-linting rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES6 Modules are static. This means that import/export can not appear inside functions, conditional statements or contain variables. import/export statements are designed to be statically analyzable, so if you conditionally want to import something, that requires running logic and thus it cannot be parsed without running the application.

More info about it https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#static-module-structure