# How do i exclude a directory with mocking files from webpack build with vue.config.js?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have a directory called `mock` at root which contains mocking data that I use to run the app in development mode. I would like to exclude them when i build for production. I notice that it is being added into bundle whenever i run `vue-cli-service build` and it is bloating my app bundle size.
I am using `vue-cli` and so I have to work with `vue.config.js`.

It is not clear from the docs or any answers on the wider web how I can specify which folders/files to exclude from the build.

Here is a snippet of my `vue.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.symlinks(false)
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new CompressionPlugin()
    ]
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: `@import "@/styles/main.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you importing those mocks somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the perfect solution, but...

If you want to exclude that directory at build time, you can try to use require `instead` of `import`. Something like this ([source](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/can-we-conditionally-import-files-in-vue-cli-3/43038/2)):

```
if (process.env.VUE_APP_MY_CONDITION) {
  require('./conditional-file.js');
}
```

But be aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62601451/1165545)!